# Seperate Resource Server(Django-oauth-toolkit) - 403 Forbidden Error(If RESOURCE_SERVER_INTROSPECTION_CREDENTIALS is used)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-oauth-toolkit

I run into an issue not sure if this is a bug. Any help would be appreciated.

Some context:

- Authorization Grant Type is Resource Owner Password Credentials where the Client Type is "confidential".
- I used csrf_exempt decorator and protected_resource decorator for a view response function in the resource server.
- Django REST Framework is used.
- Django REST Framework v3.12.4 and Django OAuth Toolkit v1.5.0 are used.
- I referred to the official documentation: https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resource_server.html
- Testing Setup is similar to the Referenced Article using two different ports: https://medium.com/@sarit.r/simple-seperate-auth-server-and-resource-server-36a7813ea8aa

Auth Server: https://github.com/pathumveyron24/Django-Auth-Server

Resource Server: https://github.com/pathumveyron24/Django-Resource-Server

Auth Server Settings File:

```
"""
Django settings for auth_server project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.2.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path
from .config import DB_ENGINE, DB_NAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_HOST, DB_PORT, TIME_ZONE

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-h6pzc5%ovv^&5o5dg0z&e8k$7y*)fufjz%2s3t(*jick@u_u9g'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'corsheaders',
    'oauth2_provider',  # OAuth2
    'rest_framework',  # API
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'oauth2_provider.middleware.OAuth2TokenMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

# -- Set up DRF to use OAuth2

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'oauth2_provider.contrib.rest_framework.OAuth2Authentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication', # To keep the Browsable API
    ),
    # 'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
    #     'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    # ),
}

OAUTH2_PROVIDER = {
    # token expiration time
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRE_SECONDS': 60 * 30,
    # this is the list of available scopes
    'SCOPES': {
        'users': 'user details',
        'read': 'Read scope',
        'write': 'Write scope',
        'groups': 'Access to your groups',
        'introspection': 'introspection',
    },
}

ROOT_URLCONF = 'auth_server.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'auth_server.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        # 'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        # 'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
        'ENGINE': DB_ENGINE,
        'NAME': DB_NAME,
        'USER': DB_USERNAME,
        'PASSWORD': DB_PASSWORD,
        'HOST': DB_HOST,
        'PORT': DB_PORT,
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = TIME_ZONE

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
```

Resource Server Settings File:

```
"""
Django settings for resource_server project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.2.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path
from .config import DB_ENGINE, DB_NAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_HOST, DB_PORT, TIME_ZONE, BASE_URL, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-gx4j%)k)sdyb#dk!&1uwpyo867v&gv-g-y)r0)#h=ff4e0z)(t'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'db_models.apps.DbModelsConfig',
    'property.apps.PropertyConfig',
    'corsheaders',
    'oauth2_provider',  # OAuth2
    'rest_framework',  # API
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'oauth2_provider.middleware.OAuth2TokenMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

# -- Set up DRF to use OAuth2

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'oauth2_provider.contrib.rest_framework.OAuth2Authentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication', # To keep the Browsable API
    ),
    # 'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
    #     'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    # ),
}

OAUTH2_PROVIDER = {
    # token expiration time
    # 'ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRE_SECONDS': 60 * 30,
    # this is the list of available scopes
    # 'SCOPES': {
    #     'read': 'Read scope',
    #     'write': 'Write scope',
    #     'introspection': 'Introspect token scope',
    # },
    'RESOURCE_SERVER_INTROSPECTION_URL': BASE_URL,
    'RESOURCE_SERVER_INTROSPECTION_CREDENTIALS': (CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET),
}

ROOT_URLCONF = 'resource_server.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'resource_server.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        # 'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        # 'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
        'ENGINE': DB_ENGINE,
        'NAME': DB_NAME,
        'USER': DB_USERNAME,
        'PASSWORD': DB_PASSWORD,
        'HOST': DB_HOST,
        'PORT': DB_PORT,
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = TIME_ZONE

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
```

Comment: RESOURCE_SERVER_INTROSPECTION_CREDENTIALS :(client_id, client_secret) in your settings.py file, are credentials from an application registered in you resource server or authentication server?

Comment: Those credentials for application registered in authentication server. Do I need to create credentials for resource server as a seperated one.

Comment: Yes, you will need to create credentials for resource server then use basic HTTP auth from resource server to make the request.

Answer (score 0):

For resource server,
register application as "**Resource owner password-based**"
This will give you client id and secret.

Use above client id and secrets as username and password with "**http basic auth**"

```
# At resource server, to check token
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

introspect_url = '<auth-server-host-here>/o/introspect/'
introspect_data = {'token': access_token_here}
introspect_response = requests.post(introspect_url, data=introspect_data, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(resource_server_client_id_here, resource_server_client_secret_here))
```

Ref:
https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resource_server.html